# show and hide method: is there something wrong with code? missing? can i show/hide the elements between radioboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

Area of the code that will be show/hide, I want to display the objects inside the radiobox (another sets of radioboxes)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this.checked);"/>
<label for="chk">Billing & Credit Management Systems</label><br />

<label class="hidden"> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" class="hidden"/>
<label class="hidden"> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" class="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by `can i show/hide the elements between radioboxes?`

Comment: i want to toggle like if i clicked the radiobox, the hidden set of radiobox will appear

Comment: sorry im just new of using stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `hiddeninputs(i)` like a function. You should use `hiddeninputs[i]` instead so that you access the value at the index.

You also don't need to get the checkbox element again since you're passing the checked value as a parameter to the function.

Fixed code:

```js
function showHide(checked) {
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

  for (var i = 0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++) {
    if (checked) {
      hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this.checked);" />
<label for="chk">Billing & Credit Management Systems</label><br />

<label class="hidden"> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" class="hidden" />
<label class="hidden"> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" class="hidden" />
```

Comment: hi can i ask again? how can i seperate the first showhide objects to the next object?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access elements using `[index]` and not `(index)`.

`[]` is used to access an array by index where `()` is used to call a method.

Also it will be easier to put the elements you want to hide inside of a single parent container.

```js
function showHide() {
  var chckbox = document.getElementById("chk");
  var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

  for (var i = 0; i != hidden.length; i++) {
    if (chckbox.checked) {
      hidden[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      hidden[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this.checked);" />
<label for="chk">Billing & Credit Management Systems</label><br />

<div class="hidden">
  <label> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" />
  <label> Web Billing </label> <input type="radio" name="area1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using pure css, however, it requires to place checkbox and element beside.

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + p {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
Male
<p>I'm Male</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
<p>I'm Female</p>
```